# Picasa 3 - All 88 'people' folders are empty - can I restore the files?

Tags: windows-7, picasa

My wife uses Picasa 3 on her laptop, and has a problem.  She has no idea how it happened but somehow the left hand panel in the Picasa 3 window shows "People (88)" but listed below it are the 88 names each with "(0)" alongside.  No thumbnails show up for any of the 'people'.

I have looked through all the menus and can see nothing that seems relevant and a search on this website has been fruitless too.

Can anyone please tell me how I can correct this situation? FYI I backed up the laptop to a portable hard drive a few days ago (using Windows Backup and Restore) and wonder if this can be used to restore the database.